# How to remove calendar icon from DateField

Tags: ext.net

How do I remove/hide the calendar icon from the `DateField` in Ext.net? I need the input only through directly editing the text.

```
DateField dtPlanDate = new DateField {
    ID = "dtPlanDate", 
    FieldLabel = Strings.PlanDate,
    LabelAlign = LabelAlign.Top,
    ToolTip = "Enter Date",
    Value = DateTime.Today,
    MinDate = DateTime.Today,
    MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),
    StartDay = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple !!!

Add one more property "HideTrigger" and set it to "true"

```
DateField dtPlanDate = new DateField { 
 ID = "dtPlanDate",
 FieldLabel = Strings.PlanDate,
 LabelAlign = LabelAlign.Top,
 ToolTip = "Enter Date",
 Value = DateTime.Today, 
 MinDate = DateTime.Today,
 MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), 
 StartDay = (int)DayOfWeek.Monday,
 HideTrigger=true
};
```

Thanks